# CiviCRM won't store Outbound email settings

Tags: database, smtp

I've just updated to 4.7.24. When I try to save Outbound email settings, I get an error with this backtrace:

```
#0 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...")
#4 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1205 ** Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction")
#10 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...")
#12 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...")
#13 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...")
#14 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(362): DB_DataObject->query("\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...")
#15 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1373): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...", TRUE)
#16 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/ACL/BAO/Cache.php(155): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("\nDELETE\nFROM   civicrm_acl_cache\nWHERE  modified_date IS NULL\n   OR  (mod...", (Array:1))
#17 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(1425): CRM_ACL_BAO_Cache::resetCache()
#18 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Smtp.php(78): CRM_Utils_System::flushCache()
#19 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447): CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp->postProcess()
#20 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Refresh.php(75): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#21 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Refresh->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp), "refresh")
#22 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp), "refresh")
#23 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("refresh")
#24 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#25 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp", "Outbound Email Settings", NULL)
#26 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#27 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#28 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#29 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("admin", "setting", "smtp")
#30 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#31 /srv/website.com/public/htdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#32 {main}
```

Can anyone help tell me what is going on?